# Is it possible to simplify my AJAX navigation code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigation

I'm still learning javascript and I'm building an ajax website that loads in content for each page from external files (e.g. test1.php, test2.php). I spent several hours cobbling together some code that works, but it feels really clunky. Any recommendations on how to streamline it? Or anything I am doing that is stupid and should be done differently?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

var projectID = $('#topNav a').each(function(){
    var projectID = $(this).attr('id');
    if(hash==projectID){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php .content';
        $('.content').load(toLoad);
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }                           
});

$('#topNav a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .content',
        newId = $(this).attr('rel'),        
        oldHeight = $('#shell').css("height"),      
        viewportHeight = $(window).height()

    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('<div/>', {
            id: newId,
            class: 'content'
        }).css({ top: viewportHeight + "px", display: "none" }).appendTo('#shell').load(toLoad);

        $('#' + newId).show(function() {
            $(this).animate({ top: "0px", queue: false}, 600);
            $('#shell > div:first').animate({ top: "-" + oldHeight, queue: false}, 600, function() {

                $('#shell > div:first').remove()
            });
        });

        var newHash = $(this).attr('id');
        window.history.pushState(null, "", "#" + newHash);

    }

    return false;
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1),
        oldHeight = $('#shell').css("height"),      
        viewportHeight = $(window).height()

    var projectID = $('#topNav a').each(function(){
        var projectID = $(this).attr('id');
        if(hash==projectID){
            var toLoad = hash+'.php .content'

            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            $('<div/>', {
                id: hash,
                class: 'content'
            }).css({ top: viewportHeight + "px", display: "none" }).appendTo('#shell').load(toLoad, function() {

                $(this).show(function() {
                    $(this).animate({ top: "0px", queue: false}, 600);
                    $('#shell > div:first').animate({ top: "-" + oldHeight, queue: false}, 600, function() {

                        $('#shell > div:first').remove()
                    });
                });

            });

        }                           
    });

});
```

});

HTML:

```
<nav id="topNav">
<a href="test1.php" id="test1" rel="content1" class="active">Test 1</a>
<a href="test2.php" id="test2" rel="content2">Test 2</a>
<a href="test3.php" id="test3"rel="content3">Test 3</a>
</nav>

<div id="shell">

<div id="content1" class="content">

    <p>Here is the first page</p>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topNav {
position: fixed; overflow: auto; top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%; z-index: 100; background: #fff; height: 80px;
}
#topNav a { margin-right: 30px; color: #a9a9a9; }
  #topNav a.active { color: #333; }

#shell { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.content { 
  position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
#content1 { background: #000; color: #fff; }
#content2 { background: red; }
#content3 { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Looks fine, though you could probably get away with using an existing plugin that gives you the same functionality that has been thoroughly tested by the community such as History.js.  this kind of question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com if you just want to get an opinion on your current code or simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

main points :

- a lot of the code is duplicated -> identify pattern & make a plugin
- you don't cache your jquery objects
- you don't use .on (&delegate event)
- you don't chain your jquery methods

restructure along those lines (it's just the core & not tested but should be a good restarting point)

```
$.fn.extend({

  tofocus : function () {

      var $tofocus=$(this);
      //put your animations/effects/your browser history management stuff
     //addcclass/removeclass 
     //chain everything .end() if necesary (like after .siblings() )
    return $tofocus;


    },      

  loadcontent : function(id) {
       var $t=$(this);
       //look if this content was already loaded 
       //if loaded $("#'+id+'").tofocus() 

      //if not ->
       var viewportHeight=$(window).height();
       var $divcontent = $('<div/>', {
                    "id"   : "content-"+id,
                    "class": 'content'
                     }).css({ 
                      top: viewportHeight + "px", display: "none"       
                 }).appendTo($t).load(id+'.php',function() {
                        $(this).tofocus();
        });
        return $t;
  }
})



$(document).ready(function() {
  //cache your content container 
  // it will  be used every time a nav button is clicked/at init & if using back/fw button -> you'll spare as much access to the dom to create the object
  var $ctt=$("#shell");
  //load first page (id from hashtag on page load ?)
  var hashfirst=...
  $ctt.loadcontent(hashfirst);


  $(document).on("click","#topNav a",function(e) {
            $ctt.loadloadcontent(this.id);
            return false
   })

   window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {

            var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1),
            $ctt.loadcontent(hash);

           });
 });
```

Comment: @MJR no worries; there was a mistake in loadcontent (it was setting the same id as the nav id - edited. Hope you're getting the plugin idea